# Content dialog height adjustment

Tags: xaml, uwp

Is it possible to disable the content dialog height adjustment when the keyboard appears on the screen. Setting minHeight does not work.

Comment: What device does your app run on? Desktop, tablet or mobile?

Comment: On mobile emulator in vs

Comment: When I launched the application on the device, minHeight fulfills its task. Thank you for directing the solution.